# Mule ESB: What "Jms session should be transacted" means?

Tags: error-handling, mule, esb, rollback

**The quick, straight to the point**

I'm testing a retry logic in JMS-subscribing flow. It is throwing

```
org.mule.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Jms session should be transacted
```

The testing is being done using the JMS ActiveMQ's management interface (localhost:8161/admin/topic), sending a message to the topic [the flow is subscribing to].

Questions:

1. Is the error being thrown as a consequence of something not
   configured correctly? Or
2. Submitting a message using the ActiveMQ's "Send To" is, by default, a
   non-transacted session? How to make it "transacted"?

**The elaborated [and longer] explanation**

The flow has, as message source, a JMS endpoint (set as a durable client); additionally, the flow is configured as "Multi-resource Transaction" type; and has a "Rollback Exception Strategy".
The flow has been intentionally configured to throw an SQL error (inserting a fixed value in a primary key column), and the "Rollback Exception Strategy" logs message.

Below is the flow:

--EDIT: and the JMS connection config as well

```
...
    <jms:activemq-connector name="PasswordResetTuT_Durable_Client_ACK_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616?keepAlive=true" validateConnections="true" clientId="PASSWORDRESET" doc:name="Active MQ" durable="true" maxRedelivery="5" >
        <reconnect frequency="7000" count="30"/>
    </jms:activemq-connector>
...
    <flow name="PASSWORDRESET-TUT.RequestConfirmation" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="/passwordreset-tut/requestConfirmation" connector-ref="PasswordResetTuT_Durable_Client_ACK_MQ" durableName="PASSWORDRESET-TUT.RequestConfirmationDurableClientName" doc:name="JMS">
            <ee:multi-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="15000"/>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        <!-- ...
                some processing goes here ...
                                              -->
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[flowVars.token="123456789ABCDEF";]]></expression-component>
        <db:insert config-ref="PasswordReset_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Insert into TOKEN">
            <db:parameterized-query>
                <!-- an insert statement that, due to the 
                     expression-component above, will attempt to 
                     insert a duplicate value into a primary key -->
            </db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
        <!-- ...
                some processing goes here ...
                                              -->
        <logger message="Finished confirming #[flowVars.token]." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <rollback-exception-strategy maxRedeliveryAttempts="5" doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="Exception throw. Attempting redelivery #[(message.inboundProperties.JMSRedelivered==false)?1:message.inboundProperties.JMSXDeliveryCount+1] for message #[message.outboundAttachments.JMSMessageID]." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
                <logger message="Redelivery exhausted. Sending #[message.inboundProperties.JMSMessageID] to DLQ." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <jms:outbound-endpoint topic="/passwordreset-tut/DLQ/requestConfirmation" connector-ref="PasswordResetTut_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
            </on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
        </rollback-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
...
```

The first "testing attempt" was done using the ActiveMQ's "Send To" [topic] (the http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp): it throws the mentioned error.

Now, it is not clear (at least for me) whether (1) the issue was caused by the method I'm using to test this, or whether (2) it was caused due to some misconfiguration [in the flow].

Comment: Adding config of `PasswordResetTuT_Durable_Client_ACK_MQ` might help

Comment: @Petter: `PasswordResetTuT_Durable_Client_ACK_MQ`'s config added in the text. Thanks for raising this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be related to needed to set the transaction type for the ActiveMQ connector, if you have a retry policy it must be a transaction so that the transaction is saved and can be retried. From the message flow if you click on the JMS connector you should see below the queue and topic settings the Transaction settings. For all inbound JMS this should be set to always begin, and for any outbound that follow a JMS inbound, they should be set to always join.